# How can I start firefox with a different profile on a Mac?

Tags: firefox

I have a MacBook Air (Mojave, 10.14.6) and for Testing reasons I need to be able to have several instances of firefox running with different **profiles** each. **At the same time**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Different user accounts and switch between them?

Comment: I need two instances of firefox running. Like in one window (the thing I can change position with, with the red-yellow-green dots on the upper left) a firefox instance with profile1 is running, and in a different window a firefox instance with profile2 is running. At the same time.

Comment: you can copy one in a folder and run one from DMG. not sure if they can make different folders in ~/Library/Cache.

Comment: What do you mean to copy "one" into a folder? One what? And what is a DMG?

Comment: I believe there is a way to run several copies of app, generally, by making copies of the app. I got an error with firefox. Maybe if you use a different profile in the command line, you would have success. You select what profile you want to by starting firefox from the command line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options command line options: /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --help

Comment: The least hocus pocus would be to get virtual machine software like parallels.  Run several VMs.  Run Firefox in each vm.

Comment: Running VM's or docker images do not seem to work (I either get errors using a 'ready-to-use' docker image, or some DISPLAY error). 
Maybe I found a better way: To start a different profile using (python-)selenium!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean launching a new instance via Terminal, you can use this:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -no-remote -P "NAME_OF_YOUR_PROFILE"
```

If you just use the `-p` option it should open the Profile Manager which should let you select a profile via the GUI, but was always buggy for me (broken blank tabs).

More documentation on the firefox command line options can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210530092017/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

Comment: Note that if the profile name doesn't exist yet, Firefox won't create it automatically. It will show the profile picker GUI, and you can create a new profile. If you pass the name of an existing profile, Firefox will load it, even with `-P` specified. As to what `--no-remote` does exactly, it's [somewhat](https://www.brycevandyk.com/dissecting-firefoxs-no-remote-option/) [complicated](https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/Vz-L_of5WZE/m/N704lSSzBQAJ).